# SyntaxError in JS

Tags: javascript

I am doing a function in JavaScript, which gets the same data from a form but removes errors or errors, which is not returning values ​​typed in the console:

> Untaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

Also, I believe the code is correct.

The code:

```js
// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

function subtmitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = getInputVal('name');
    var email = getInputVal('email');
}

function getInputVal(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

Comment: Could you share the entire file?

Comment: The code you posted compiles just fine.

Comment: GetInputVal is defined after it's first call, so the function is unknown at this point. Move the function direct under "document.getElementById(...". Then the function is known before its called first,

Comment: @ThomasLudewig due to hoisting the order does not matter in this case.

Comment: Then you know more then me :) If i try it i get always a error ;)

Comment: At a glance I see a typo that could be problematic-- your function is defined as `subtmitForm` but you try to bind it as `submitForm`.  I would have expected a different error than "Unexpected end of input" but I wouldn't expect it to build/function as written above as `submitFunction` is never defined.  Beyond that, if there is still an issue, it would be helpful if you posted the full error and perhaps the full file, as there isn't enough to go on here to provide you with much additional useful guidance.

Comment: @ThomasLudewig the only error in the above code seems to be the typo. maybe this is also causing your error here.

Answer (score 0):

you just have a typo in the function `subtmitForm(e)` name, it should match the callback `submitForm` name in the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the same code. There is no error

```js
function submitForm(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var name = getInputVal('name');
    var email = getInputVal('email');
    
    alert('name:'+name+' email:'+email)
}

function getInputVal(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form id="contactForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```